# Equivalence between different forms of the Axiom of Infinity

Tags: set-theory

In Zermelo-Frankel set theory, the Axiom of Infinity is often stated as

> "There exists a set $X$ such that $\emptyset \in X$ and such that if $y\in X$ then $S^{+}_1(y)\in X$",

where we take the successor function as $S^{+}_1(y) = y\cup \{y\}$. I believe the original formulation for the Axiom of Infinity by Zermelo had a different form, where the successor function was instead $S^{+}_2(y) = \{y\}$.

Let's call the form of the Axiom of Infinity with $S^{+}_1$ "Infinity 1" and the form with $S^{+}_2$ "Infinity 2". Changing from "Infinity 2" to "Infinity 1" made the axiom easier to work with, but the two formulations should be equivalent.

How can we prove that "Infinity 1" and "Infinity 2" are equivalent under the remaining ZF axioms?

Comment: As @Nishant notes, we can recursively define maps from the finite von Neumann ordinals ($0$, $n +1 = n \cup \{n\}$) and the finite Zermelo ordinals ($0$, $n+ 1 = \{ n\}$). Replacement then implies that the set of the former exist iff the set of the latter do. But it's worth noting that in the absence of Replacement this can fail in both directions. See http://www.jstor.org/stable/421182?seq=8&uid=3738032&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21106300019561#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: Did Zermelo even had an axiom of infinity?

Comment: @AsafKaragila If the wikipedia page for Zermelo set theory is to be believed, then yep; and it was Infinity 2.

Comment: @GME: Interesting, I somehow recalled that there wasn't something like that; but maybe I was thinking about the very early axiomatizations, and maybe I was just thinking about how the Zermelo encoding of $\Bbb N$ cannot be extended transfinitely.

Comment: @AsafKaragila What do you think goes wrong in the transfinite case? (Assuming we take unions at limits.)

Comment: @GME: Yes, taking unions. But it doesn't "reflect" the nature of the construction. The natural limit would be to have some $\{x\}$ such that every Zermelo-integer is in the transitive closure of that set; but this is impossible since the construction leads to a set $x=\{x\}$, which is already transitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're allowed to use Replacement, you can recursively define a map from an inductive set of the second kind to an inductive set of the first kind by just setting $f(\varnothing)=\varnothing, f(S_2^+(y))=S_1^+(f(y))$, and then the image, which is a set by Replacement, will be an inductive set of the first kind.